# Flowchart (decision tree) for translating Chumash words

Tags: grammar-dikduk

Looking for a 'flowchart' that can help me break down a Chumash word to determine the 'Shoresh' (root word), as well as the meaning of the prefixes, suffixes etc.

The goal is to be able to translate words of Chumash with relative ease, allowing the student to 'know what they don't know'

Does anyone know of any such tool?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/71171/759

Comment: Very similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9667